# Adding spatial columns to Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working with Laravel 5.5 and MySQL 5.7 and I have a table that stores travels data with origin and destination in two spatial columns (*POINT* type).

I'm trying to get this fields working with Eloquent in a transparent way, I've managed how to transform the longitude and latitude to model attributes on retrieving the data from database overriding newQuery() method in my Model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Travel extends Model
{
    public function newQuery()
    {
        return parent::newQuery()->select('id',
            DB::raw('ST_X(origin) AS origin_x, 
                    ST_Y(origin) AS origin_y, 
                    ST_X(destination) AS destination_x, 
                    ST_Y(destination) AS destination_y'));
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to do the same for **new Travel()** and **$travel->save()**, because I need the insert or update statement to always use the MySQL **POINT(x,y)** function.

Do you have any idea on how to do it in a good way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial

Comment: I've tried it and works well, but it stores POINT(longitude, latitude) in database and I need POINT(latitude, longitude)

Comment: https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial/blob/master/src/Types/Point.php#L11 Just reverse the constructor?

Comment: @BeLi POINT(long, lat) is in that order because semantically we write coordinates in (X, Y) notation.